# Set delegate to parent view controller

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios4

I have three view controllers in my app pushed to the navigation controller. When I'm on the third view controller I want to send a message to the first one. I think a delegate is the way to go here, but I'm not able to set it correctly.

In my third view controller's h-file I have this:

```
@protocol AddSudokusViewControllerDelegate

- (void)saveSudoku:(Sudoku *)sudoku;

@end

@interface [...]

    id<AddSudokusViewControllerDelegate> delegate;

[...]

@property (nonatomic, retain) id<AddSudokusViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
```

Then I synthesize it in the .m file.

In my first view controller I have this (.h):

```
@interface SudokusViewController : UITableViewController <AddSudokusViewControllerDelegate>{
[...]
}
- (void)saveSudoku:(Sudoku *)sudoku;
```

So far so good I think. Now I want to set the delegate of the third view controller to first when I create it in the second controller. I thought I could do it like this, but it doesn't work.

```
sudokuDetailViewController = [[SudokuDetailViewController alloc] init];
[sudokuDetailViewController setDelegate:[[self navigationController] parentViewController]];

[[self navigationController] pushViewController:sudokuDetailViewController animated:YES];
```

Am I doing this the right way or is there another approach when you have three controllers like this?

Best Regards
Linus

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this,

```
sudokuDetailViewController.delegate = [self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
```